# Cannot see all the labels on the x asis in an ssrs column chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a column graph as shown below. It shows only a few x axis labels. I want it to show all the x axis labels. Is there a way this can be done ? I tried changing the size of the chart and this doesnt work

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question:

[SSRS chart does not show all labels on Horizontal access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692628/ssrs-chart-does-not-show-all-labels-on-horizontal-access)

Best answer was:

> To fix this, under the "Chart Axis" properties set the Interval value to "=1". Then all the labels will be shown